# Syntax Error jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a syntax I can't figure out.

```
        $(this).append(<a href="#">free</a>);
```

And here is the error message in the console:

```
       Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I have no idea, what this error message wants to tell me, because it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Oh God! where are the quotes. Use single quote `$(this).append'(<a href="#">free</a>');`  A good editor will catch these errors in first place

Comment: Added: $(this).append("<a href="#">free</a>");

Comment: Still doesn't work. " missing ) after argument list.

Comment: You can't wrap your string with `"` since it contains `"` (unless you escape it) - use single quotes as @Tushar and the answers suggest.

Comment: Use single quotes, `$(this).append('<a href="#">free</a>');`

Comment: Got it. You have to use quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks, timeout, but updated my second comment

Comment: @DenisDoan When you want to use double-quotes inside string use single-quotes as delimiters of the string and vice-versa. If you want to use double-quote inside the string delimited by double-quote you can escape the inner quote by preceding it with \

Answer (score 2):

Simple, you are missing quotes:

```
$(this).append('<a href="#">free</a>');
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the parameter you pass can be:

"DOM element, array of elements, **HTML string**, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements."

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).append('<a href="#">free</a>');
```

Comment: Got it. You have to use quotes instead of double quotes.